# why spring @schedule do not work with @Lazy

Tags: spring, annotations, scheduled-tasks

```
    @Lazy
    @Component
    public class ScheduleTest {
       @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
       public  void  doSomething(){
          System.out.println("do something"+ new Date());
       }
   }
```

when i set the lazy(value=false),it works.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following [Jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12872), it works from `Spring 4.3 RC2` version.

Logically it didn't work, because `@Lazy` means that don't instantiate this bean, unless it is injected somewhere, but `@Scheduled` proxy was created when the bean was instantiated.

Comment: Same problem here with spring 5.x